# Force a post to call an action in a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code made in a MVC5 project:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {

        var idAd = $('#id').val();

        $.post("Controller/Action", { id : idAd });

    });
});
```

But when I click the button I can't get the code call the action in the controller. The click event is fired but not the post action. The parameter that receives the action is called "id" the same used in the post method in the jquery code.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: There are way too many similar questions on SO.

Comment: Show your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnDelete').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var idAd = $('#id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': idAd }),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // result
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: When I put an alert after e.preventDefault(), the alert doesn't show, and of course, the rest of the code is not executed.

Comment: What's you HTML for button? it must be something like this: `<button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>` http://jsfiddle.net/g3gyvwa3/

Comment: Yes. If I put an alert before preventDefault sentence the alert is fired. After it not.

Comment: I forgot to put `e` as a parameter. check my answer now. `click(function (e) {...`